# Permutation in scheme

Tags: scheme, permutation

Question: Write an inductive definition of a function all-permutations that takes a list of numbers as input, and
returns the set of all permutations of that list of numbers, as output, represented as a list of lists.

```
(apply append(map(lambda (i) (map (lambda (j)(cons i j))
                                                (permute (remove i 
lst))))lst)))))
```

I had came up with core code of the problem. But I need to express the solution in pure english and mathematical notation, with no variables or data structure mutation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
# Python program to print all permutations with
# duplicates allowed

def toString(List):
    return ''.join(List)

# Function to print permutations of string
# This function takes three parameters:
# 1. String
# 2. Starting index of the string
# 3. Ending index of the string.
def permute(a, l, r):
    if l==r:
        print toString(a)
    else:
        for i in xrange(l,r+1):
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]
            permute(a, l+1, r)
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l] # backtrack

# Driver program to test the above function
string = "ABC"
n = len(string)
a = list(string)
permute(a, 0, n-1)

# This code is contributed by Bhavya Jain
```

This is a code done in python of ur problem found in geekforgeeks

Source: Mathword(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Permutation.html)

Comment: thank you for ur comment. However, I need the answer in Scheme language.

Comment: @NickSun why did you accept this answer, then, if it doesn't meet your requirements?